# Set-Location using variables?

Tags: powershell

I am having some problems with the following script.  I am trying to do a Windows Form, with 2 Text Box.
The $CaseName contains the Case Name, and it will create a Folder inside the Drive K, in Server1
The $InputBox contains the name of the sub-folders which will be created inside the Case Name.

I believe I am having problems with the following lines:
It creates the directory inside K, but it does not create the directories within $CaseName

```
 Set-Location "\\Server1\K$"
        New-Item $CaseName.Text -type directory
        Set-Location "\\Server1\K$\$CaseName\"
```

Error Message

```
Set-Location : Cannot find path '\\Server1\K$\111\' because it does not exist.
At C:\APPS\Scripts\CreateFolder - Test.ps1:54 char:9
+         Set-Location "\\Server1\K$\111\"
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\Server1\K$\111\:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

Here is the full script

```
# Load required assemblies
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

# Drawing form and controls
$CreateFolder = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $CreateFolder.Text = "Create Folder"
    $CreateFolder.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(800,400)
    $CreateFolder.FormBorderStyle = "FixedDialog"
    $CreateFolder.TopMost = $true
    $CreateFolder.MaximizeBox = $false
    $CreateFolder.MinimizeBox = $false
    $CreateFolder.ControlBox = $true
    $CreateFolder.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
    $CreateFolder.Font = "Segoe UI"

# CaseName    
    $CaseName = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $CaseName.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,50)
    $CaseName.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,25)
    $CaseName.ScrollBars = "Vertical"
    $CreateFolder.Controls.Add($CaseName)

# Inputbox    
    $Inputbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $Inputbox.Multiline = $True;
    $Inputbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,100)
    $Inputbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200)
    $Inputbox.ScrollBars = "Vertical"
    $CreateFolder.Controls.Add($Inputbox)
    
# adding a label to my form
$label_message = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $label_message.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(8,8)
    $label_message.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(240,32)
    $label_message.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
    $label_message.Text = "Create Folders!!"
    $CreateFolder.Controls.Add($label_message)

# create folders from LAB


# add a button ti create folder
$button_ClickMe = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $button_ClickMe.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,120)
    $button_ClickMe.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(240,32)
    $button_ClickMe.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
    $button_ClickMe.Text = "Create Folders Now!!!"
    $button_ClickMe.Add_Click({
        

        Set-Location "\\Server1\K$"
        New-Item $CaseName.Text -type directory
        Set-Location "\\Server1\K$\$CaseName\"

        $button_ClickMe.Text = "Folders were created"
        ForEach ($Folder in $Inputbox.lines) {
            New-Item $Folder -type directory
            }
    })
    $CreateFolder.Controls.Add($button_ClickMe)

# add a button to save as
$button_ClickMe2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $button_ClickMe2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,80)
    $button_ClickMe2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(240,32)
    $button_ClickMe2.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
    $button_ClickMe2.Text = "Location to create folders"
    $button_ClickMe2.Add_Click({
  
        ForEach ($Folder in $Inputbox.lines) {
            New-Item $Folder -type directory
            }
    })
    $CreateFolder.Controls.Add($button_ClickMe2)

# show form
$CreateFolder.Add_Shown({$CreateFolder.Activate()})
[void] $CreateFolder.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Try changing `Set-Location "\\Server1\K$\$CaseName\"` -> `Set-Location "\\Server1\K$\$($CaseName.Text)\"`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Mathias, your answered fixed the issue!